# Error when redirecting a domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The thing is I have one domain in different languages, and I´m not able to do some redirects like this:

I have Spanish http://www.domain.es/inicio
And English http://www.domain.en/inicio

Now, I need to move my page http://www.domain.en/inicio to http://www.domain.en/home 
Both domains are using the same .htaccess and I´m not able to do a simple:

```
Redirect 301 /inicio http://www.domain.en/home
```

Cause that will redirect the spanish /inicio to /home too.

Also tested

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.en/inicio/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.en/home/ [R=301,L]
```

But thats also failing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /inicio/
RewriteRule ^inicio/(.*) /home/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You should redirect the content of the folder /inicio to folder /home if I got it right. There is no need to redirect everything since the domain is the same

The request should be GET since the users are accessing your website pages